# Intercommunication between Vespa application

Tags: docker, bigdata, vespa

I want to create an application in Vespa whcih fetch the data from some appications and feed into another applications.Example:

I have three applications which have data named **Location** , **User** and **Banner**.Now what I want to create an app in vespa which fetch the data from **Locaton** and **User** and fed to **Banner**.

How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If "fetch" is document lookups: Use the document API (Java or REST, see doc) to fetch and the document API (Java or REST), or the Java HTTP client to feed.

If fetch is a query: Do the same but send a query HTTP request, or write a Searcher which constructs the query from some GET request and use the Java Document API to write documents back from it.

This should probably just be one application with different data types.

Comment: Thanks Jon for answer.Can you please suggest me how to use HTTP/REST in Searcher to fetch(GET request) and feed(PUT request). Also, please upvote my question.

Comment: Just use some standard HTTP client, not sure what language you want. (If you do it from inside Vespa, use the Document API, not HTTP).

Comment: ok Thanks Jon, I am using Document API and its working fine.Please upvote my question.